# How to create bins in a reliability diagram

Tags: r, bin, reliability

I created a logistic/logit model with a binomial response variable using

```
model <- glm(response~predictor1+predictor2+...)
```

and then I used the predict function to create a new data frame

```
outcome <-data.frame(predict(model,newdata=IndependentDataSet,type="response"),as.numeric(as.character(Independent$ResponseVariable)))

names(outcome) <- c("Pr","Obs")
```

I can use one of the following functions

```
plot(verify(data$obs,data$pr),CI=TRUE) 
attribute(verify(data$obs,data$pr))
```

to create a plot that looks like this
[image: to create a plot that looks like this]

or

```
reliability.plot(verify(data$obs,data$pr))
```

from

```
library(verification)
```

to create a reliability diagram.  I am wondering how I can separate the bins based on specific values.  For example, the model that I am evaluating is based around a climatology of 19% (0.19) and I want there to be a bin at (1/3)*climatology, climatology, and go up by (2/3) of climatology for the proceeding bins.  How can I do this?

Additionally, I have seen the bins represented as circles that are proportional in size to the percent of the data that is at that bin.  Does anyone know how to make a more aesthetically pleasing reliability diagram in R?  Any recommendations are welcome.

This is how I would like my diagrams to appear
[image: This is how I would like my diagrams to appear]

Comment: When asking for plotting help be sure to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. We have no idea what you are seeing. And vague questions about making them "more aesthetically pleasing" are kind of off topic. Ask a more specific question.

Comment: @MrFlick I have added more information to the question in response to your comment. My question regarding the bin values is specific and should not yield any problems with ambiguity.  Any help I can receive on this topic is appreciated.  The last question regarding the looks is simply a bonus if anyone happens to know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest could be using

```
    trace("attribute.default",edit=TRUE)
```

or whichever other function. 
In this way, you access the source code and edit it. These changes affect only the current R session.